# lower bound for the smallest singular value of non-singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a non-singular real $n\times n$ matrix $A_\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$, where **some** of the entries depend on $\epsilon$; in particular they behave as $\mathcal{O}(1/\epsilon^2)$. Assume that the eigenvalues of $A$ go either to infinity or 1 as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Can one claim that the singular values do not approach zero as well? In other words, can one find a **non-vanishing lower bound** for the smallest singular value, as $\epsilon\to 0$?

Comment: At this level of generality your claim can't be true. The $(1\times 1)$-matrix $(1/\varepsilon^2)$ is a counterexample. Your singular value is $1/\varepsilon^2$ and has no $\varepsilon$-independent lower bound.

Comment: You're absolutely right! But let me correct myself. I am actually worried about vanishing lower bound, but your example is going to infinity which is fine with me. Thank you for your point, I modify the statement.

Comment: For any $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, $|\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_k|\leq\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$ (with singular and eigenvalues decreasing in absolute values with increasing index). That might help.